# Saving HTML in memory to S3 AWS Python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
from io import StringIO
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

display = # Altair Charting

buff = StringIO(display.save(str_obj, 'html'))

s3.upload_fileobj(buff.read(), BUCKET, 'index.html')
```

I think I full example would complicate the issue, so I left Altair charting commented out.

Anyway, I've tried to implement the vast amount suggestions for saving objects and files to AWS S3 buckets, but I'm not understanding.

Saving to disk is as simple as:

```
display.save('index.html')
```

Getting this onto S3 seems extremely difficult comparison.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.  Perhaps the `upload_fileobj` is not the correct method, but I've gone around and around trying to make this work.

The specific error with this method is `ValueError: Fileobj must implement read`

UPDATE:

```
buff = StringIO(display.save('str.html'))

s3.put_object(
   Bucket=BUCKET, 
   Key=f'{DASHBOARD}{mkt_type}/{symbol}/index.html',
   Body=buff.read()
   )
```

Results in the 0 Byte file `index.html` on my Bucket

UPDATE 2:

```
str_obj = StringIO()
display.save(str_obj, 'html')
buff = str_obj.read()

s3.put_object(
    Bucket=BUCKET, 
    Key=f'{DASHBOARD}{mkt_type}/{symbol}/index.html',
    Body=buff
    )
```

This also doesn't work.  I just can't believe saving a file to S3 is this complicated.  Hindsight note: I didn't have the `getvalue()` method required for `buff`

SOLUTION:
This is not the first time I've struggled with S3 files, so I'm probably leaving this for my own future reference.  That said, it is still not clear to me why I couldn't save the '.html' file in string form.

```
import boto3
from io import StringIO
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

display = # Altair Charting

str_obj = StringIO() # instantiate in-memory string object
display.save(str_obj, 'html') # saving to memory string object
buf = str_obj.getvalue().encode() # convert in-memory string to bytes

# Upload as bytes
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=BUCKET, 
    Key=f'{DASHBOARD}{mkt_type}/{symbol}/index.html', 
    Body=buf
    )
```

Comment: Presumably you can get the HTML content from 'display' as a string. Try s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key='index.html', Body=s) where s is a string containing the contents of your HTML document.

Comment: I think I implemented per your suggestion, however, the contents are not storing to S3

Comment: I don't know why this is such an issue... if you have any other suggestions, they are appreciated

Comment: Note that the boto3 documentation indicates that upload_fileobj() expects the file-like object you pass to it to be in binary mode so io.BytesIO() is probably more appropriate than io.StringIO(). That said, it is simple to upload an existing file using s3.upload_file() and it simple to write a string to a file using s3_put_object(). I'd recommend getting one of those to work first because if you can't then there are bigger problems to solve here.

Answer (score 3):

From boto3 docs:
[put_object](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)

> Body=b'bytes'|file,

Which means that Body should be file handle or byte string. 
So there are (at least) 2 possible ways to upload:

By passing file handle to Body:

```
with open('index.hml', 'rb') as f:
    s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=f'{DASHBOARD}{mkt_type}/{symbol}/index.html', Body=f)
```

By passing bytestring to Body (supposing display.save() return string):

```
buf = display.save('str.html').encode() # converting str to bytes
s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=f'{DASHBOARD}{mkt_type}/{symbol}/index.html', Body=buf)
```

Comment: yeah, display.save() doesn't return a string directly, but you helped my figure it out.  Thank you.