# pandas-profiling aws glue to s3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-glue, pandas-profiling

I am trying to load the html output of pandas-profiling to s3 from my glue job but am getting empty files. Its an issue with saving the file in memory to s3. I tried the following solution but no luck [Saving HTML in memory to S3 AWS Python Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086739/saving-html-in-memory-to-s3-aws-python-boto3)

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
from io import StringIO

#Pull all file names/keys from S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def get_matching_s3_keys(bucket, prefix='', suffix=''):
    """
    Generate the keys in an S3 bucket.

    :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
    :param prefix: Only fetch keys that start with this prefix (optional).
    :param suffix: Only fetch keys that end with this suffix (optional).
    """
    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Prefix': prefix}
    while True:
        resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        for obj in resp['Contents']:
            key = obj['Key']
            if key.endswith(suffix):
                yield key

        try:
            kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
        except KeyError:
            break
        
#Pull all file paths and append to list
tables_list = []

for key in get_matching_s3_keys('mybucketname', 'processed/', '.csv'):
    print(key)
    tables_list.append(key)
    
for i in tables_list:
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucketname', Key=i)
    df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
    
    profile = ProfileReport(df, title = 'My Data Profile',  html ={"style": {'full_width':True}}, minimal=True)
    profile.to_file(i.lstrip("processed/").rstrip(".csv")+".html")
    
    str_obj = StringIO()
    profile.to_file(str_obj, 'html')
    buf = str_obj.getvalue().encode()
    
    # Upload as bytes
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket='mybucketname', 
        Key=i.lstrip("processed/").rstrip(".csv")+".html", 
        Body=buf
        )
```

Any thoughts on what I need to tweak with my code?